# Creating a new column, if Column A has a blank cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python script that reads csv and put it into a dataframe. I want to do read the csv and where Pixel Type column is blank, create a new column and put the Parent (in this case it will be google_2023, gumgum_2023) in the new column, like the excel sheet.

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')
# Create a new column to store the Parent value
df['Parent'] = ''
# Iterate over the rows of the DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     pixel_type = row['Pixel Type']
     # Check if the Pixel Type is blank
    if pd.isnull(pixel_type):
    parent = row['Pixel Group / Pixel Name']
else:
    # Set the Parent value for the current row
    df.at[index, 'Parent'] = parent
# Print the updated DataFrame
print(df)
```

Comment: Are all of these segments the same length?

Comment: I wouldn't read the file directly into a dataframe but read the file directly and create a list of lists properly formatting the data and then convert the list of lists to a dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the answer with this code:

```
# Find the index of the "Pixel Group / Pixel Name" column
                pixelgroup_index = df1.columns.get_loc('Pixel Group / Pixel Name')
                # Create a new column to store the Parent value
                df1.insert(pixelgroup_index + 1, 'Parent Pixel', '')
                # Iterate over the rows of the DataFrame
                for index, row in df1.iterrows():
                    pixel_type = row['Pixel Type']
                    # Check if the Pixel Type is blank
                    if pd.isnull(pixel_type):
                        parent = row['Pixel Group / Pixel Name']
                    else:
                        # Set the Parent value for the current row
                        df1.at[index, 'Parent Pixel'] = parent
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate your dataframe using -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"type_":np.tile(np.array(["", "imp", "imp", "imp"]),3), "data": np.repeat(np.array(["data"]), 12)})
```

the output of which is -

```
type_   data
0       data
1   imp data
2   imp data
3   imp data
4       data
5   imp data
6   imp data
7   imp data
8       data
9   imp data
10  imp data
11  imp data
```

(apologies for the output format)

SOLUTION

```
# Find the indices where blank is there.
indices = df.loc[df["type_"]==""].index

# Creating index_pairs.
index_pairs = list(zip(indices[:-1], indices[1:]))

# Modifying the index pairs to consider the first_blank till the element before the next blank.
index_pairs = [(index_pairs[0][0], index_pairs[0][1]-1)] + [(pair[0], pair[1]-1) for pair in index_pairs[1:]]

# Creating a temporary dataframe to store the new columns.
temp_df = pd.DataFrame()

# The new column names are assumed to be col0, col1,....,colN
for i in range(len(index_pairs)):
    start, stop = index_pairs[i]
    temp_df[f"col{i}"] = df.iloc[start: stop+1, 1].reset_index(drop=True)

# Appending the last data to the dataframe.
temp_df[f"col{i+1}"] = df.iloc[index_pairs[-1][-1]: , 1].reset_index(drop=True)
```

The final *index_pairs* look like -

```
[(0, 3), (4, 7)]
```

Note- Using reset_index to not consider the original index of the slice taken from "iloc".

**THIS IS AN INITIAL ATTEMPT. YOU MIGHT HAVE TO DO SOME MODIFICATIONS BUT THIS IS A GOOD START.**

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll play around with it and see if I can make it work

Comment: Your welcome, let me know how this goes!